# How to Hit Download content url in the backend and forward the respose to the next page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have one url to download content i want to hit that url in the  backend to start downloading and forwad the response to the aany other jsp page.

When i write window.location.href(download_full_url) its  working fine only to download the content but side by side i want to forwared the respose to another jsp page.

```
<script>
function yes(content_name,previous_page) {

    //downloadContent(content_name);
    window.location.href = "download_full_url";
    backPage(previous_page);

}
</script>
```

To  download the content in the backend process, i have also made one js function to hit the url without waiting to get the response but its not working here is my another js function.

```
function downloadContent(content_name) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","download_full_url?"+content_name="+content_name, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When i call abovefunction instead of `window.location.href=download` url its not working its call the `backpage()` after calling `downloadContent` function the response to previous page.

```
<script>
    function backpage(previous_page) {
        window.location.href = previous_page;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try put the redirection inside your servlet page at the end of your download complete code.

Comment: This is not possible   6 to 10 projects  are dependent on downloading url  projects so i cant do that